# How to use image for oracle database table 11gR2

Tags: image, forms, oracle

I have created emp table to store employees information and their PP size photo.
this table has empno (number), emp_image_link(varchar2), .... etc fields.
`empno` is auto generated using a database trigger (`max empno+1`).

Image : I don't want to store images into the database since  I believe it will cause problems in terms of size, performance and portability. So images should be in the file system at `D:\images\`
and images URL should be `D:\images\empno.jpg`, which means `emp_image_link` field will contain only the image link.

I have searched Google a lot about this, everyone is discussing about how to store into the database.
I did not find any information about how to store only the link instead of the image.
I am going to use Oracle Forms Developer 11gR2.
Can anyone give me an idea of how I can do that please.

Thank you in advance.

Murshed Khan

Answer (score 2):

> "i dont want to store images into the database since it will cause
>   problem in terms of size, performance and portability i believe. so
>   images should be in the file system"

Your points are not valid ones.

**Size.**  Passport photos are pretty small, so unless you are storing pictures with extremely high pixel counts they won't take up a lot of disk.  Either way they will consume comparable amounts of space in the database and on the OS.

**Performance.** The only possible concern would be the network traffic between the database server and the middle-tier server.  This would be a function of size, so may or may not be a real issue.  Using na OS file store would introduce a time delay while you retrieve the JPG for each record.

**Portability.**  An all-in-the-database solution is more portable than what you're proposing.  Nothing breaks like directory paths.

One thing you haven't considered but you really should is DML on the employee records.  If the pictures are stored in the database they are committed in the same transaction as  (hence consistent with) the rest of the data, they are backed-up at the same time and they are recoverable in the same window.  None of which applies to an OS directory on a separate server.

---

> "Storing in the file system  ... I got the solution using BFILE "

BFILE is the mechanism for linking a database record with an OS file.  So it is the appropriate solution for the problem as you define it. But the BFILE points to files on the database server, so  you would lose the only possibly efficiency to be gained from not storing records in the database, the network traffic between the database and middle tier servers.  BFILEs would not be backed up with the database or subject to any transactional consistency.

---

> "empno is auto generated using a database trigger (max empno+1)"

Another bad idea.  It doesn't scale and more importantly it doesn't work in a multi-user environment.  Please use a sequence, they're designed for this task.

Comment: Hi APC, Good morning and thank you for the reply. I wanted to use the file system because I was thinking (for backup) to use exp utility and simple copy paste in file system. dmp file is comparatively smaller, easy to transfer and images are easy to transfer using a memory stick. This is more comfortable for me. However I got your points so I will store then in the database. empno : sequence will miss some numbers even if I just attempt to use this. But because of multi-user issue (as you mentioned), I will be using sequence from now. Thanks. Murshed.

Comment: EXP is not a backup tool.  It is for transferring data between databases.

Comment: Storing in the file system : last night (before you replied) I got the solution using BFILE. But according to your suggestion, I will not use it now. Thanks again. Murshed.